# Simulate Bivariate Beta Distribution , BIBETA(6, 20, 2) in R

Tags: r, random, statistics, beta-distribution

I need to simulate bivariate beta distribution, BIBETA(6,20,2) in `r`. I am looking for a package/ code that would generate bivariate beta distribution. I couldn't find the r function for this distribution.

Is anyone know which `r` function can be used for this simulation?

Comment: This is not a standard distribution. How is it defined?

Comment: Let BIBETA(a,b,c), then f(x,y) = 1/Beta(a, b, c) * {(x^((b-1)) * (1-x)^(a+b-1) * y^((c-1)) * (1-y)^(a+c-1))/(1-xy)^(a+b+c)}

Comment: Is there a probabilisitc representation?

Comment: Ok I have found one. See page 2 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5881.pdf). It's easy to simulate from three Gamma distributions.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Ok thank you

Comment: An answer is contained in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315865/bivariate-beta-distribution